# Efficient ways to measure the degree of independence of a moderately large number of variables

Tags: independence, estimators

I have a process that generates values for variables $x_{1}, x_{2}, \dotsc, x_{n}$ where $n \approx 40$, and the value of each $x_{i}$ lies between $0$ and $1$. The process generates these in batches of $100$ each. That is, one output of the process is a $100\times n$ matrix $X$ where the $j$th column of $X$ forms the $100$ values of variable $x_{j}$.

I would like to check if the variables $x_{1}, x_{2}, \dotsc, x_{n}$ are mutually independent, as evidenced by the values $X$ output by the process. What would be a fast way to do this?

I am looking for some kind of statistic/measure that I can compute efficiently from the entries of the matrix $X$, that will give me a good estimate of how close the variables are to being mutually independent.

For my purposes it is OK if this is a "one-sided" measure, in the following sense: if the variables are close to being mutually independent, then the measure is close to zero (say). But if the measure is close to zero, that doesn't necessarily imply that the variables are close to being mutually independent.

Are there any such measures known? I don't know much statistics, so I apologize if this is something very evident to an expert. My searches only turned up ideas for testing if *two* variables are independent, in the way I described. For example, I could compute their correlation or covariance, and see if this number is close to zero. But I am not sure what to do with the $40$ variables that I have. E.g.: would it be enough to do sum up the pairwise correlation of all the $\binom{40}{2}$ pairs of variables?

Answer (score 0):

In microarrays, a *metropolis plot* is a common tool for finding bivariate associations in large $p$-data. Essentially, you perform a Fisher correlation test for all p*(1-p) bivariate combinations, and plot the -log base 10 of the p-value as a barchart, possibly sorted in descending order. A horizontal line is drawn usually based on some kind of significance threshold, for instance a Bonferroni correction for 20 comparisons would have a line at $-\log_{10}(0.05/20) = 2.6 $.

```
set.seed(123)
x <- matrix(rnorm(1000), nrow=10)
i <- combn(x = 1:100, 2, simplify = F)
p <- sapply(i, function(i) cor.test(x[, i[1]], x[, i[2]])$p.value)
plot(sort(-log(p, base=10)), type='h', xlab='', ylab='-log 10 (p)')
abline(h=-log(5e-4, base=10)) 
## note Bonferroni value is 0.05/100 choose 2 = 0.05/4950 <1.1e-5
```

[image]